# Determinant of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, determinant

We know that polynomials are a vector space, as they are non-empty, have the elements $1$, $0_V$, an additive inverse and define an operation $\times : \mathbb{K} \times V \to V$ and $+ : V \times V \to V$.

The basis of the polynomial vector space $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is the set $\{1,X,X^2,X^3,...,X^n\}$ (assuming that all polynomials have the maximum degree of $n$.

One could define a isomorphic function $\Phi:V \to V : f \mapsto 4f-3$.
As this function is a linear function, one could assume that one could calculate the Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors etc. of $\Phi$ -- just as we do it for 'regular' vector space transformations $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

However, while starting to calculate, I got stuck on one question: *How do I calculate the characteristic polynomial of $\Phi$?*
I of course know the formula $CP_\Phi(λ)=\text{det}(\Phi-λ)$, but it does not get me very far in this case, as I do not know how to calculate the determinant of a polynomial (remember, that $\Phi$ is a polynomial in this case).

Should I transform $\Phi$ into a representation matrix $A_\phi$ and solve $\text{det}(A_\Phi-λ)$ instead? What would be the elements of this matrix? Should I take the polynomial basis $\langle 1,X,X^2,...\rangle$?

I have the feeling that I am near the goal, but that I have missed something obvious or trivial.

**Disclaimer: English is not my native language, do please forgive any 'wrong' technical term.**

---

### EDIT №1:

[See my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2900135/277212) for explanation of my errors.

Comment: $\phi$ is *not* a linear function, but an *affine* function. The associated linear function is just multiplication by $4$, and its eigenvalues, eigenvectors, &c. are obvious.

Comment: @Bernard: Oh, damn - you are right, a translation is of course affine, not linear. That was rather stupid of me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized my mistakes:

*first error:* $\Phi(f)=4f-3$ is an *affine* transformation, not a linear one. (Thanks [@Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202857/bernard))

*second one:*

I have to view polynomials $f\in V$ as vectors, e.g.:

Let $g(X):=4X^2-8X+2$
and $\Phi:V \to V : (aX^2+bX+c)\mapsto -2bX^2-(c+3b)X+4a$

$g$ can be represented as $\vec{v}_g:=(4, -8, 2)^T$.
$\Phi$ can be represented as
$A_\Phi:=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -2 & 0\\0 & -3 & -1\\4 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.
The calculation of $\Phi(g)$ can be written as $A_\Phi * \vec{v}_g$ which would yield the result $(16, -22, 16)^T$ corresponding to the correct 'output' polynomial of $\Phi(g):x\mapsto 16X^2-22X+16$.

Calculating the determinant and characteristic polynomial etc. can be done with the matrix $A_\Phi$ and is a piece of cake ;)

Comment: If you did $\Phi (f)=4f$ instead,  it would be linear, and the matrix would be $4I$...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to put it in the canonical base of polynomials.
In general, a polynomial can be viewed as a matrix in the space of polynomials.